# what is the difference between additions?

Tags: java

I'm starting to learn Java..I am very excited.
First code is not return result as my want..

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Yusuf
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner text = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a,b;
        System.out.print("Enter first number:");
        a = text.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter second number:");
        b = text.nextInt();
        System.out.print("a + b = " + a+b);
    }
}
```

This code's result is "a + b = 1525" (if a=15 and b=25 (i am giving random number for example))

Why above code isn't work such as this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Yusuf
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner text = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a,b,c;
        System.out.print("Enter first number:");
        a = text.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter second number:");
        b = text.nextInt();
        c = a+b;
        System.out.print("a + b = " + c);
    }
}
```

This code returning 40 for same numbers..
What is the difference? Absolutely i need to use different variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When used with strings, the `+` operator does string concatenation. If you add numbers to the end of a string with `+` the numbers will be converted to strings first.

Your statement:

```
System.out.print("a + b = " + a+b);
```

takes the string `"a + b"` and concatenates the value from `a` as a string and then concatenates the value from `b` as a string.

It should work the way you want if you do this:

```
System.out.print("a + b = " + (a+b) );
```

The extra parens for `(a+b)` will cause that addition to be evaluated (as an `int` addition) before the string concatenation occurs.

Comment: @Joseph - actually, this comes *after* normal operator priority / precedence.

Comment: "Operator precedence" is the term usually used in programming. Things in parens get evaluated first, and then certain operators get evaluated before others as listed here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html - note that you can "nest" parentheses, e.g., `(a + b) * (x / (y-6))` - the expression in the innermost parens is evaluated first...

Answer (score 0):

`+` does not always mean addition.  When used with a string, it does concatenation.

When you do

`System.out.print("a + b = " + a+b);`

you are concatenating `a` and `b` onto the string.

In other words, you are doing

`(("a + b = " + a) + b);`

which evaluates to

`"a + b = 15" + b`

which evaluates to

`"a + b = 1525"`

When you do

`c=a+b`

and then

`System.out.print("a + b = " + c);`

you do the addition **first**, and then you concatenate the resulting value (40) onto the String.

Comment: I need to create new variable in a sense?

Comment: you need to not do string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

In your first code when you say `"a + b = " + a + b`, you are doing a string concatenation. Whatever you add to a string will be come a string.

In your example,

first `"a + b = " + a` will become `"a + b = 15"` and then b will be contactenated.

So, it will become `a + b = 1525`

Where as in your second example, you are separately doing the addition and then concatenating to the string. So you are getting the desired result.

you can do `"a + b = " + (a + b)` aswell.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line:

```
System.out.print("a + b = " + a+b);
```

The '+' operator in 'a + b' is being interpreted as a string concatenation not an integer addition.

Change it to this:

```
System.out.print("a + b = " + (a+b));
```

---

The reason you have to do this is a combination of the overload resolution rules for the '+' operator, and basic Java operator precedence rules.

- If *either* operand of '+' is a String, then the operator is a string concatenation, and the non-String operand (if any) is converted to a String.
- If you have `x op y op z` where 'op' is the same operator, then it is equivalent to `(x op y) op z`.

---

If you put that together, `"a + b = " + a+b` (where `a` and `b` are `int`) is equivalent to:

```
    ("a + b = " + a) + b
```

and hence

```
    "a + b = ".concat(Integer.toString(a)).concat(Integer.toString(b))
```

The corrected version `"a + b = " + (a + b)` is equivalent to:

```
    "a + b = ".concat(Integer.toString(a + b))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do `System.out.print("a + b = " + (a+b));` so that the compiler can understand that it has to first add `a and b` and than concatenate.